# Dropdown List not showing correct SelectedItem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, html.dropdownlistfor

I'm trying to make a page to create a Recipe, a recipe can contain multiple tags.

This is the HttpGet that gets me the view to create a recipe

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ViewResult Index() {
        return View(new RecipeViewModel { 
            TagsFromDb = repository.Tags.ToList()
    }
```

This is my ViewModel for the page

```
public class RecipeViewModel : Recipe {
    public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; } = new List<Tag>();
    public List<Tag> TagsFromDb { get; set; }
```

This is the button in my view that calls the action to create a new tag

<input type="submit" asp-action="AddTag" value="Add tag" class="btn btn-primary" />

And this is the Action in my controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult AddTag(RecipeViewModel model) {
        model.Tags.Add(new Tag());
        return View("Index", model);
    }
```

This is the code in my view that creates a new dropdown for each tag added

```
 <div class="form-group">
                @if (Model.Tags.Count > 0) {
                    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Tags.Count; i++) {
                        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
                        foreach (Tag tag in Model.TagsFromDb) {
                            items.Add(new SelectListItem() {
                                Text = tag.Name,
                                Value = tag.ID.ToString(),
                                Selected = tag.ID == Model.Tags[i].ID ? true : false
                            });
                        }
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <select asp-for="@Model.Tags[i].ID" asp-items="items" class="form-control">
                        <option value="">Vælg tag</option>
                    </select>
                    <button class="btn-danger" asp-action="RemoveTag" type="submit" name="index" value="@i">X</button>
                </div>
                    }
                }
            </div>
```

And this is the remove action in the controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult RemoveTag(RecipeViewModel model, int index) {
        model.Tags.RemoveAt(index);
        return View("Index", model);
    }
```

And here comes the headache..

Adding tags and saving their values is working fine, and so is deleting them.
However, say I have these 3 tags added:
[3 tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doIU3.png)
And i press the X button on the middle Tag, the Tag at the correct index gets deleted, but when the view reloads it removes the bottom tag instead of the middle tag, like this:
[2 tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfJjt.png)
So the values in the model are correct, but the values in the dropdowns are not.

How can I make the dropdowns show up with the correct values?

Hope this makes sense for someone, still studying and have not started on javascript yet, so any solution without would be preferred, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It would seem posting here made me solve my own issue!

Instead of using the asp-items taghelper for the options i made a foreach on the SelectListItems in the itemlist, and made it set the selecteditem in an if/else

Here is how I fixed it

```
   <div class="form-group">
                @if (Model.Tags.Count > 0) {
                    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Tags.Count; i++) {
                        var items = new List<SelectListItem>(Model.TagsFromDb.Select(tag => new SelectListItem() {
                            Value = tag.ID.ToString(),
                            Text = tag.Name,
                            Selected = tag.ID == Model.Tags[i].ID ? true : false
                        }).ToList());
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                            <select asp-for="@Model.Tags[i].ID" class="form-control">
                                <option value="">Vælg tag</option>
                                @foreach (SelectListItem item in items) {
                                    if (item.Selected) {
                                        <option selected="selected" value="@item.Value">@item.Text</option>
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        <option value="@item.Value">@item.Text</option>
                                    }
                                }
                            </select>
                            <button class="btn-danger" asp-action="RemoveTag" name="index" value="@i">X</button>
                        </div>
                    }
                }
            </div>
```